# Check if currently active element is any kind of input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to detect if currently active element is any kind of input field. Currently I have this:

```
var activeElement = document.activeElement

if (activeElement && (activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input' || 
    activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'textarea' || 
    activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'select' || 
    activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button')) {
    return false
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I am using Vue JS, so if there is a solution with Vue API that is ok too.

Comment: What about `select`, `button` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre oh yes you are right, this too... Have updated my code

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could put all the element types you want to check in an array and check if your active Element is in it:

```
var activeElement = document.activeElement;
var inputs = ['input', 'select', 'button', 'textarea'];

if (activeElement && inputs.indexOf(activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: if statement should be: if (activeElement && inputs.indexOf(activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {

Answer (score -1):

With Jquery you can try the following

```
if(elem.is('input')){
//yes it an input element.
}
```

If you want a check for a specific input type

```
if(elem.is('input:radio')){
//yes it an input type = 'radio' element.
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you would down-vote for a jquery solution. Many people use jquery. Just make sure you wrap your elem in jquery selector `let isInput = $(document.activeElement).is('input');`